# How to index my website

Tags: indexing, search-engine

I just come across Elastic Search, I have done installation and sample indexing and searchs.
Now I want to use this for my website. For that how to create indexes for my website? do I need to store entire web pages content as index??

Thanks,
Nehatha

Comment: This might be better on webmasters.SE.

Comment: @John, I didnt get you. can you please explaing in more detail plzzz

Comment: I thought that this was more a webmaster question than a programming question, so you might try asking at webmasters.stackexchange.com.  (Sorry for my original shorthand.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES doesn't come with a crawler built-in - You will need to write a crawler to index websites. There are plenty of F/OSS crawlers/spiders you can use - Nutch being one of them.

Here is a thread that might be of interest:
http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Suggestions-for-places-to-start-for-a-crawler-td900225.html

If your needs are lightweight, you can easily hack together a crawler in your fave language within a few hours.

Comment: Thank you Mikos. They provided PERL based crawle, can you suggest PHP/Java based crawler that suits for ElasticSearch integration.